# Problem importing gcloud libraries on GCE using Python 2.7 code

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

A few years ago I wrote code in Python 2.7 to perform calculations on the Google Compute Engine platform.  I am self-taught in Python, Bash and all things Gcloud related, so please be gentle!

I use a boot script which installs some Python packages, creates directories and sets ownership, copies some input data from a Gcloud storage bucket and then runs a "no hangup" python command which sets calcs running.  The compute engine instances are running Debian11 images.  The bits of boot script that I think are pertinent to my query are:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -yq install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
sudo pip install --upgrade google-auth-httplib2
    
...making directories
...setting ownership

nohup python path/to/code/myscript.py &
```

The last time I used this code was October 2022, and it worked perfectly.

When I try to run the same code now, it fails.  In the first few lines of the python script, there is a command:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

The above line causes a fatal error ("ImportError: No module named google.cloud").  To try to isolate the issue I made a "blank" compute engine instance and ran each line of the boot script in turn.  The command to install python-pip appears to be obsolete (?) and recommends to use:

```
sudo apt-get -yq install python3-pip
```

Doing this means that the boot script gets through all of the package installations, but the "python" command is not found.  I suspected that this might be related to Python2.7 being obsolete (I thought that happened in 2020 though?) and the Debian image coming with Python3 as standard, so I tried to 'force' installation of Python2.7 by using:

```
sudo apt-get -yq install python
```

This allows me to use the "python" command to start Python2.7, but when I try to import libraries that I have supposedly installed in the code above, i.e.:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

I still get the "ImportError: No module named google.cloud" issue described above.  After some reading on links such as [this](https://sebhastian.com/python-no-module-named-google-cloud/#issue-with-multiple-versions-of-python) I suspect that my issue is something related to versions of Python and the client libraries getting 'mixed up' between them - i.e. I'm installing the packages 'for' Python3, but the Python I am trying to run is Python2.7.  I feel that the changes I've made to the boot script are creating a horrendous message and Im getting myself further into trouble!  I do not possess the skill or patience to update my code to Python3, especially since I am not sure my hunch about versions is correct, and wondered if there is an elegant ( = lazy?!) solution that might allow me to work around this?  Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.  In case it is useful, my current (still not working) version of the boot code is:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -yq install python3-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
sudo pip install --upgrade google-auth-httplib2
sudo apt-get -yq install python
```

Comment: Google has not supported Python 2.x for a couple of years. I do not believe that the current libraries are even tested with Python 2.x. Migrate your code to Python 3 if you want support from the community. Note: do not install the package `google-cloud`. That was deprecated and will break current libraries.